# show in terminal in eclipse enterprise application opens up both the IDE terminal and windows terminal

Tags: windows, eclipse, terminal

Right click on a project -> Show in -> Terminal opens up both IDE terminal and windows terminal at the same time.
How do I make sure only the IDE terminal opens up?
I tried the same thing in STS and it opens a single IDE terminal.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"eclipse enterprise application"_? Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers? But which version (is it up to date?) and on which operating system? Please show also what you have in the preferences _Terminal > Local Terminal_.

Comment: @howlger I use Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers. Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0) ,Windows 11.  It's up to date

Comment: Eclipse 2019-12 is more than three years and 13 releases behind. There have been a couple of changes according to the _Terminal_. Please upgrade.